# Stylesheets not applied in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

Using Watir with Chromedriver.  When running tests (not headless), my stylesheets are not applied.  When running chrome normally (not testing) my stylesheets show up.

What's the deal?  This didn't happen yesterday.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57)
- watir 6.2.1
- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: What does the console say? Difficult to determine cause with this info.  Hit f12 in chrome, check the console tab and let us know if you have any errors or warnings (cross-origin, for example).

Comment: See @orde's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are accessing the application-under-test via embedded credentials.  Chrome v59 removes support for embedded credentials in subresource requests.  Here's what the [documentation](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856) says:

> Drop support for embedded credentials in subresource requests. (removed)
>
> We should block requests for subresources that contain embedded
>   credentials (e.g. "http://ima_user:hunter2@example.com/yay.tiff").
>   Such resources would be handled as network errors

Comment: Orde, thank you for your response.  As part of our tests, we are using embedded credentials because we are running behind Apache Basic Auth.  While not causing issues directly accessing the site, obviously it caused issues with our stylesheets.

Comment: Glad it helped.  It was a surprise to see it working manually and then failing via automation.

Comment: Is there any way to get passed this issue? I've tried a few options such as --allow-file-access-from-files and --allow-external-pages with no joy

Comment: Not AFAIK. You could use firefox, but that's just a workaround. You could also remove the browser-based authentication and put the site-under-test behind a VPN (or--possibly--whitelist the IPs that you're testing from).  YMMV.

Comment: I'm in discussions with the project about putting it behind a VPN. For now, I'm running in Firefox.  Thanks for the response